# How to play video inside WebView android with link from google drive

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Im writing code to show video from webview which link is from google drive, but i cant play the video

[image]

And this is my code looks like

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) child.findViewById(R.id.webview_player_view);
 WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
 webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
 webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

 webView.loadUrl(fact.getValue());
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Note : fact.getValue is the google drive url

Comment: Use advanced Webview they handled all these things very efficiently.
https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Comment: @RehanSarwar another thanks it works, but when i click fullscreen button the webview is stuck >_<

Comment: Can you share your code snippet.?